# CKAN stats on downloaded resources for an Organization

Tags: ckan

Is it possible for organizations to view stats on how many downloads are made for each resource file or dataset that has been published? if so How?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ckanext-googleanalytics extension that adds ga even tracking to the resource downloads links, and you can preview the downloads in the analytics interface.